# Simple generic method with TreeMap<K, V> as parameter

Tags: java, generics, key-value, treemap

I'm attempting to write a generic method that iterates TreeMap entries to get a value with its key (I'm using a custom comparator to sort the map based on values and as a result have broken the get() method, but that's not the problem I'm solving here). I've got the following so far, but I'm not seeing why the symbols 'K' and 'V' are not resolved - even though they're declared on the TreeMap that is passed in.

```
private V forceGet(TreeMap<K, V> sortedMap, K targetKey) {

    for (Map.Entry e : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        K key = (K) e.getKey();
        V value = (V) e.getValue();
        if (key.equals(targetKey)) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I confess not being an expert on generics, so apologies if this should be obvious.

Comment: Your method is not generic. Here's the tutorial on [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: Also read [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I know your question was about generics, but are you sure that iterating over the entry set will even work if you've broken the `TreeMap`?

Comment: Yes that works - the TreeMap keys and values are all intact, but apparently the get() method uses the same custom comparator that I created for my value sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare the generic parameters, before the return type:

```
private <K, V> V forceGet(TreeMap<K, V> sortedMap, K targetKey) { ... }
```

Comment: Also the `Map.Entry` should be `Map.Entry<K,V>` and then there will be no need to cast `key` and `value`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to declare K and V in your function:

```
private <K,V> V forceGet(...)
{
       //your code
}
```